# Format integer in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a difficult time to format integer in asp script

The format of the integer right now is ######. I would like to format it to ####-##. For ex: Format 201602 to 2016-02. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks much!

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="From" runat="server" DataSourceID="ShipDate"DataTextField="intYearMonth"> <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"/> </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: any way you can actually store it as 2 separate values or as a `DateTime`? your way seems risky.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this after everything loads with a `For Each`...

**Note** - No error checking here you may want to handle that...

```
For Each item As ListItem In DropDownList1.Items
   item.Text = item.Insert(4, "-")
Next
```

**Output** - `2016-02`